# How to better manage multi state models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

Let's say I have model `Campaign` which can have multiple boolean states at the same time:

`drafted` : Just a draft

`suspended` : Suspended after being active

`pending` : Awaiting approval

`paused` : Campaign is paused until client resumes it.

I thought about using state machines, i like their DSL and the conventions they provide, but it's just for one concurrent state, I don't want to lose the previous status. for instance with state machines (one string field rules them all):

If  I suspend a campaign, then the client pauses it while suspended, and resumes it, it goes active and the suspension status has vanished.

Any one knows how to deal with this? I love StateMachines conventions but I still want concurrent statuses to persist.

Comment: Why can't you have boolean attributes for each of the attributes you mention above, and maintain state independently with a state machine? Just because the model's state changes doesn't mean every unrelated boolean attribute needs to be reset. In your example, when the `resume` transition were to take place, check the `:suspended` status and if `true`, transition the state machine back to `suspended` instead of `active` (or whatever the active state is).

Comment: It seems like you could use a state machine for draft, pending, approved and paused but suspended should be a boolean, admin-only field.